# Android Repeat Task

Tags: android, task, repeat

Android Repetitive Task
here is my code but the sound is not repeated

```
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
              public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                  mPlayer.start();
                 } 
               });
            }};
            timer.schedule(task, 0, 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use media player, you can use

```
mPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

by the way ,your repeat timer task is fine.